# How to configure statet code Snippets?

Tags: r, eclipse, code-snippets, statet

I would like to set my working directory to the location of the file on which I'm working.

In eclipse

> Windows > preference > Statet > Run/Debug > R Code Snippets

Opens a dialogue to run code snippets.

[image]
Doing the following allows me to run a `setwd()` command using the path to the ressource selected in the project explorer.
What command do I need to point to the window / Rfile I'm currently working in ? (the one currently active in the windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Selecting the variable `$container_loc$` does the trick, but only if the windows containing the current script has focus.

[image]